# Can't Paste Data path from Custom Properties into Driver

Tags: rigging, drivers

so here is the situation:

- I'm doing this all in pose mode
- created an armature system
- added a bone called > Properties
- added a custom properties to this bone (bone properties)
- copied the data path (Shift + Ctrl + C)
- selected another bone > this bone has a rotation constraint > influence
- add driver to that influence channel
- driver settings
- averaged value
- object > armature
- bone > tried to paste the data path
- doesn't work > error > failed to find "

this worked before, im using blender 3.3 here

Comment: easier if you had "Copy as new driver" (instead of copy-data-path), and then paste driver into the influence field.  error free.

Answer (score 1):

After some experimentation, I'd agree that the following is a tad screwy.  It has to do with how (in python scripting) you traverse the object and armature hierarchies to get to their custom properties.

If you define a bone-CP when in Edit mode, the cp path must be referenced via the Armature.   If you define a bone-CP when in Pose mode, the cp path must be referenced via the object:
[image]

Why?  Just to confuse and frustrate us?  Example file with both defined on the "thigh.L" bone and driver on the "upper_arm.L" bone:  [image]

It would have been easier if you had "Copy as new driver" (instead of copy-data-path), and then paste driver into the influence field!

Comment: Actually, there is a "copy as new driver" option right? I tried that out and it works out for me.

i guess i have to just change the way i copy data info in the future

Comment: @Wonkey -- there's always someone's easier suggestion on this site ... after I've pulled my hair out!  ;)